# Why is the magnitude of this vector $\sqrt{14}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I don't understand why, when normalizing the vector $(2,-3-i)$, we get $(2,-3-i)/\sqrt{14}$. When I find the magnitude of the vector, I do

$$=\sqrt{(2)^2+(-3-i)^2}=\sqrt{4+8+6i}=\sqrt{12+6i}$$

How am I supposed to get $\sqrt{14}$??

Comment: Find the magnitude of each component, and then the magnitude of the vector as a whole.

Comment: You should actually take $\sqrt{|2|^2+|-3-i|^2}$ instead. Hope that helps

Comment: The space $\mathbb{C}^2$ is just the space $\mathbb{R}^4$ ( + some structure). What Ross Millikan does (multiplying complex conjugates) is easier to remember than finding out the magnitude of $(2,0,-3,-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find the magnitude of a vector with complex components, you want the absolute square of each component, where you multiply it by its conjugate.  so 
$$|(2,-3-i)|=\sqrt{(2)^2+(-3-i)(-3+i)}=\sqrt{4+10}=\sqrt{14}$$

Comment: Ah, that was what I was missing. Thanks!